# using a variable 'status' in ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm issuing a strange comportment using an ajax request with jquery, in the code below the header.STATUS can't be retrieved in a variable called 'status' it seems to work fine with another variable name, I'd like to know why ?

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: "GET", 
     url: myConnect.prototype.URL, 
     data: params, 
     error: this.errorHandler,
     success: function(data){ 
          response = JSON.parse(data);

          status = response.STATUS;
          if(status.SUCCESS){ //never true since status is not an object.
               console.log('success !');
          }
     }
});
```

data is : `{"STATUS":{"SUCCESS":1,"DESCRIPTION":""}}`

the status variable is set as a string, I can see its value in the chrome's Watch Expression view :

```
status: "[object Object]"
```

but if I call this variable 't' (or anything else) the condition will be true and it will log '*success !*'

any explanation ?

EDIT : 
the response parsed object as displayed by chrome :

```
 response : Object
      STATUS: Object
           DESCRIPTION: ""
           SUCCESS: true
      _proto_: Object
 _proto_: Object
```

Comment: note that `data` does not exist... you called it `dara` in your function param

Comment: First, set your `dataType` to `"json"` and remove `JSON.parse`, let jQuery do the parsing for you. Though, in theory that shouldn't make any noticiable difference to the result. What do you get if you console.log data after it is parsed as an object?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example?

Comment: Looks like our friend is implicitly declaring global variables in the success callback. That is not a great idea.

Comment: sry for the mistake on 'data'  and thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make status local it should work

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: "GET", 
     url: WellcomsConnect.prototype.URL, 
     data: params, 
     error: this.errorHandler,
     success: function(dara){ 
          response = JSON.parse(data);

          var status = response.STATUS; // make it local
          if(status.SUCCESS){ //never true since status is not an object.
               console.log('success !');
          }
     }
});
```

**EDIT:**

This explanation below is actually in Chrome only - Firefox works fine - IE9 doesn't work

the reason it's not is because [`window` has a status property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.status) already and your Status object is  getting stored as a String - `[object Object]` instead of an object

[image]

I tested this in IE9/Firefox/Chrome

[Only working if Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/UKGP3/) - using global

Then

[Working in all](http://jsfiddle.net/3wByp/) - using local

Comment: Hehe I knew not having `var` would cause an issue. Nice work.